# How can I yield a palette image from another thread to WPF UI thread?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I want to create/manipulate a palette based image asynchronously and yield that image to the WPF UI thread.

In order to yield a freezable object from another thread to the UI thread it's required to freeze the object.

However, I'm not able to freeze the image when it is palette based. The `BitmapPalette` derives from `DispatcherObject`, so I cannot freeze it.

How can I yield a palette image from another thread to WPF UI thread?

Here's the sample code:

```cs
internal static Task<BitmapSource> GetImageAsync()
{
  return Task.Run<BitmapSource>(() =>
  {
    BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();

    bi.BeginInit();
    bi.UriSource = new Uri(@"test.jpg");
    bi.DecodePixelWidth = 16;
    bi.EndInit();

    FormatConvertedBitmap fcb = new FormatConvertedBitmap(bi, PixelFormats.Indexed2, new BitmapPalette(bi, 4), 1);

    // Required for the UI thread to be able to use the bitmap.
    // However, fcb.CanFreeze is false, though.
    fcb.Freeze();

    return fcb;
  });
}
```

... and here's the warning (error) I get:

```html
System.Windows.Freezable Warning:
  2 : CanFreeze is returning false because a DependencyProperty
      on the Freezable has a value that is a DispatcherObject
      with thread affinity
```

---

@Clemens:

Here's the workaround I came up with. It resembles your solution very much. I omitted the copying though.

```cs
private void CopyBitmapSourceToUi(BitmapSource image)
{
  BitmapSource uiSource;

  uiSource = BitmapFrame.Create(image);
  uiSource.Freeze();  // locks bitmap and enables access by UI thread

  Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Source = uiSource);
  Thread.Sleep(10);   // WPF requires a short while to render the picture. During that period, you cannot create a WritableBitmap from the source image. So I added a minor delay.
}
```

With my solution, though, it looks like I cannot create a WritableBitmap from the source while WPF renders the image (see comment above).

Comment: It does not seem possible to freeze a FormatConvertedBitmap with a non-null DestinationPalette. What is your actual goal here, just reduce the number of colors?

Comment: I'm writing an image recognition program. This is just a minimum sample to be able to reproduce the issue. I'm providing dedicated colors in the `BitmapPalette` constructor to be able to search for these colors in the image.

Answer (score 0):

You may create a copy of the paletted bitmap like shown below.

For simplicity, it uses `Indexed8` instead of `Indexed2`, so that each byte in the source pixel buffer contains exactly one palette index.

The target bitmap uses the `Rgb24` format, so each byte of the source buffer is mapped to 3 bytes of the target buffer. You could as well use `Bgr24`, but you would have to change the indexes in the for-loop.

```
var palette = new BitmapPalette(bi, 4);
var fcb = new FormatConvertedBitmap(bi, PixelFormats.Indexed8, palette, 1);

var sourceBuffer = new byte[fcb.PixelWidth * fcb.PixelHeight];
var targetBuffer = new byte[3 * sourceBuffer.Length];

fcb.CopyPixels(sourceBuffer, fcb.PixelWidth, 0);

for (int i = 0; i < sourceBuffer.Length; i++)
{
    var color = palette.Colors[sourceBuffer[i]];

    targetBuffer[3 * i + 0] = color.R;
    targetBuffer[3 * i + 1] = color.G;
    targetBuffer[3 * i + 2] = color.B;
}

var bitmap = BitmapSource.Create(
    fcb.PixelWidth, fcb.PixelHeight,
    fcb.DpiX, fcb.DpiY,
    PixelFormats.Rgb24, null,
    targetBuffer, 3 * fcb.PixelWidth);

bitmap.Freeze();
```

Comment: Are you sure you meant `BitmapSource.Create()` and not `BitmapFrame.Create()`? That's actually the workaround I came up with, too. I omitted the copying, though.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot add code samples in a comment, so I add my version to my question above.

Comment: Ah, yes, right ... I have this issue with your solution: With this solution of yours I'd need in-depth knowledge of the image format. However, I need to create arbitrary images asynchronously and copy the result to an `Image` control then. I believe you solution requires too much overhead to be generally applicable for all kinds of image formats.

Comment: Please pardon me for not making the general aspect of my question clear in the first place.

Comment: I don't think so. It was your idea to use a paletted bitmap, so you control the first intermediate format, i.e. Indexed8. The second one, Rgb24 or Brg24, is fixed, i.e. always the same. Both are independent of the pixel format of the original image.

Comment: After further investigation it turned out there is a threading issue in WPF. See https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/4396 for reference.